# Trying to upgrade Admob

Tags: android, admob

I have been using AdMob on android since June this year, however their policy has changed now. I am trying to follow their guide to upgrade to the new AdMob however it does not seem to work. I tried to follow their video as found [here](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3077517?ref_topic=3011419&rd=1).

But surprisingly I don't find any upgrade button as it is defined in the video. Could anyone please help me in figuring this out?

[image: Screen Shot:]

Comment: I got the same problem, for me the reason was that I am living in a country where the upgrade was not available yet. I used a VPN to finally do the upgrade.

Comment: Man this is so irritating!

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade is being rolled out world wide. It would seem that it has not rolled out to your area yet, hence no upgrade button.

Don't sweat it. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks man, but atleast they should specify that its not been rolled out. Ive wasted important hours on this issue